# TList<T> where T is a record

Tags: delphi, generics

I have the following source but I have a compiler error at List[0].ID := '';

Why cannot I update the record directly from TList and I have to go through the record

```
program aTList;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.SysUtils;

type
  ARecord = record
    ID: string;
  end;

var
  List: TList<ARecord>;
  Rec: ARecord;

begin
  List := TList<ARecord>.Create;
  List.Add(Rec);
  Rec.ID := 'abc';
  List[0] := Rec;
  List[0].ID := 'abc';// compiler error
end.
```

Comment: Nitpick: you don't get a runtime error; you get a compile-time error ("Left side cannot be assigned to", E2064).

Comment: One possible solution is to make a list of pointer to the record. But this have other side effects.

Comment: @andreas thanks for spotting that one. I have edited it now.